# Difficulty in writing a recursive solution to "Rat in a maze" problem

Tags: java, recursion

My question is essentially a doubt about recursion. I was solving the classic "Rat in a Maze" DFS traversal problem. My input was an `n*n int` array `a[][]` where for indices `i` and `j`, `a[i][j]` could either be `0` or `1`. `0` meant the hypothetical rat couldn't visit the element and `1` meant it could. The rat could only go downwards(`"D"`) or rightwards(`"R"`). The task was to output all movement Strings like `RDRDRD` that represented the rat's movement through the maze. The rat starts from `a[0][0]` and must reach `a[n-1][n-1]`. The input was the maze itself.

I wrote the following code

```
 public boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int[][] a, int n)
 {
    if(x >= 0 && x < n && y >= 0 && y < n && a[x][y] == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }
 public ArrayList<String> printPath(int[][] a, int n)
 {
     ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
     solve(0,0,new String(), res,a,n);
     return res;
 }
 public void solve(int x, int y, String sol, ArrayList<String> res , 
 int[][]a, int n)
 {
     if(x == n-1 && y == n-1)
     {
         res.add(sol);
         return;
     }
     y++;
     if(isSafe(x,y,a,n))
     {
         solve(x,y,sol + "R",res,a,n);
     }
     else 
         y--;
     x++;
     if(isSafe(x,y,a,n))
     {
         solve(x,y,sol+"D",res,a,n);
     }
     else
         x--;
 }`
```

where `isSafe` check whether a movement is permitted, `printPath` is a helper function for printing the output and `solve` is the recursive function used to traverse the maze.`a` represents the maze array as a 2-D array.
For the input

```
{1 0 0 0 
 1 1 0 1 
 0 1 0 0 
 0 1 1 1}
```

I get the following output

```
DRDDRR DDDRR
```

Obviously the second string represents an incorrect result.

However, when I changed the `solve` function like so

```
public void solve(int x, int y, String sol, ArrayList<String> res, 
int[][]a, int n)
 {
    if(x == n-1 && y == n-1)
    {
        res.add(sol);
        return;
    }
    if(!isSafe(x,y,a,n))
       return;
    solve(x+1,y,sol + "D",res,a,n);
    solve(x,y+1,sol + "R",res,a,n);    
    return;  
 }
```

I get the correct output. What I am failing to understand is what resulted in the incorrect output in my previous solution, as to me the two solutions are logically similar.
I know it's a long read, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first solution the variable increment `y++` is only undone if the call to `isSafe` with the incremented value comes back negative and is carried over to the check of `x` if it was true. This means that the down check on a field that has a valid neighbor to the right, in particular the field [1][0], will be performed with the incremented value of `y` instead of the correct one.

If you modify the first solution like this

```
y++;
if(isSafe(x,y,a,n)){
    solve(x,y,sol + "R",res,a,n);
}
y--;
```

the first solution will work correctly as does the second one. In the second solution the increment is only done on the function argument, not a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

A general advice is to not modify your input. And it is the case that your problem comes from just that. Here I modified your code so it doesn't do that. It's much more readable in my opinion and now you're sure of what x or y value you're using.:

```
if (isSafe(x, y + 1, a, n)) {
    solve(x, y + 1, sol + "R", res, a, n);
}
if (isSafe(x + 1, y, a, n)) {
    solve(x + 1, y, sol + "D", res, a, n);
}
```